# Reading three signals sent serially on Simulink from Arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, xbee

I am sending three signals from one Arduino mega to another using xbees. On the receiving end I am using these signals in a Simulink code to control servo motors. Currently it is set up to read from analog pins without the wireless set up. With the wireless technology the signals are all being sent and received through one serial port. I believe I would need to change the inputs in Simulink to a serial receive block instead of an analog pin block. The problem is the documentation for the serial receive block says you can not assign more than one serial receive block to the same serial port. If anyone has a solution to this it would be greatly appreciated!

receiving code

```cpp
int received1; 
int received2;  
int received3;  
void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}  
void loop() {  
  if(Serial.available() )  
  {  
    received1, received2, received3 = Serial.read();  
  }  
}
```

transmitting code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);
  int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
  int sensorValue3 = analogRead(A2);
  Serial.write(sensorValue1, sensorValue2, sensorValue3);
  delay(1);       
}
```

Comment: How are the three signals encoded in the bitstream?

Comment: Here is my receiving end arduino code. Not sure if its correct yet.  I will add it to the question.

Comment: What does your sending code look like?

Comment: I will add that to the question as well

Comment: What is the result shown on the serial monitor?
Let the three values received on the receiver code be shown on the serial monitor. Tell us exactly what do you have? Is it a trash? or nothing is received?

Comment: Repost from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599430/reading-three-signals-sent-serially-on-simulink-from-arduino

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your data into a packet and then send the packet to Simulink.

You have tried this by this line in your transmitting code:

```cpp
Serial.write(sensorValue1, sensorValue2, sensorValue3);
```

However, as you can see from the [Serial Write documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/) it does not work like that. The function cannot accept 3 arguments.

Try this instead:

```cpp
Serial.write(sensorValue1);
Serial.write(sensorValue2);
Serial.write(sensorValue3);
```